# ¿Como puedo limitar el número de eventos que permite un dia en FullCalendar v5.0?

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando poner un limitar de eventos, en el que el calendario no acepte mas de dos eventos por día, he intentado esto:

```
           dayMaxEventRows: true, 
            views: 
            {
                timeGrid: 
                {
                 dayMaxEventRows: 2 
                }
            }
```

Pero lo unico que hace es mostar los eventos restantes a modo de link. Si alguien me pudiera echar un cable, lo agradecería.

Comment: Es para insertar máximo 2 eventos, o que solo se vean 2 eventos?

Comment: Para insertar maximo dos eventos, pero ya lo tengo, desde mi servicio php le pasé el número de eventos de un dia y con un condicional lo solucioné, ahora estoy intentando hacer que salga una imagen como evento en vez de un  texto. Es que como cambiaron la mayoría de funciones con la v5 de fullcalendar, no me aclaro mucho.

Comment: Por lo que leí de la documentación, `dayMaxEventRows` es para visualizar solamente X eventos en los días, no para insertarlos

Comment: Si, por eso está mal. la función que necesito es dayClick, pero no se como extraer el evento en el dayclick, tan solo puedo obtener la fecha, no el evento de esa fecha.